# Sencha Touch 2 store get record

Tags: extjs, get, touch, store, record

I have a problem.

I have 2 store files (1 event and 1 places). I'm loading these stores from a database. Now the problem is that in the event store there is a field called {id_place}. This field contains a number which is also a number in the places store. Now what I need to do is get the name from the place of the {id_place}. So the {name} is a field in the places store. So what I need is a function to get a record from another store and then get the {name} from that store. So I send the id_place to the placestore, then I need to find the record with that id and I need to get the field {name} from that record. I don't know if I'm making sense, it's kinda hard to explain. I hope this can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
showPlace: function(id_place){
                var placeUrl = 'http://admin.hishanghai.info/sencha/places.php?action=read&callback=callback&id=' + id_place;
                store = new Ext.data.Store({
                    model: 'android.model.Placesmodel',

        autoLoad: true,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'scripttag',
                        url: placeUrl,
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'place'
                        },
                        extraParams: {
                            action: 'read'
                        }
                    }

                })
                //var naam = Ext.getStore('Placesstore').getById('id_place').get('name')
                //var Record = store.getAt(id_place);
                //var naam = store.getById('id_place').get('name');
                var naam = store.get('name');
                return naam;

                 }
```

This code creates a store with the info from 1 record. Now I only need to access the name field. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
 showPlace: function(id_place){
            var placesstore = Ext.getStore('Placesstore');
            var i =0;
            var placeid = 0;
            var aRecord;
            while(placeid != id_place){
                aRecord = placesstore.getAt(i);
                placeid = aRecord.data.id;
                i+=1;
                }
            var naam = aRecord.data.name;
            return naam;
             }
```